# Как узнать настоящее разрешение экрана вне зависимости от DPI?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0

Почти всегда рекомендуют использовать `System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` И в обычных ситуациях он у меня показывает реальную ширину в 1920. Однако если я в настройках Винды выберу увеличенный DPI, допустим не 100%, а 125%, то результатом `System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` будет уже не 1920, а 1536.

В общем, я ищу, как добыть реальное разрешение экрана вне зависимости от DPI.
Необходимо для консольной программы.

Comment: А зачем его добывать? Кстати, а в манифесте прописать, что твоя программа сама разбирается с масштабированием - не поможет? Или тебе не для этого?

Comment: Масштабирование моей программы тут вообще не причём. Кстати, почему-то удалили из вопроса упоминание что мне это нужно для консольной программы...

Comment: Судя по [истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/924749/revisions) - и не было упоминания, вы его только что добавили.

Comment: @AK, но была метка, которую удалили. Но вообще да, по ней об этом не догадаешься.

Comment: При том что в описании метки console сказано что нужно её указывать если речь идёт о консольной программе.

Comment: @Raf-9600 только когда вопрос касается работы с консолью. Если вам просто нужно решение, работающее в любом типе приложений, досточно метки windows

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, мне нужно решение работающее именно в консольном приложении, остальные типы приложений не интересуют.

Comment: @Raf-9600 Тут суть в том, что код, работающий в консольном приложении, всегда будет работать в любом другом (десктопном) типе приложений, так как в приложении Winforms или WPF можно также создать консоль и пользоваться ею. (Хотя обратное обычно неверно.) Как следствие, нет смысла ставить метку console только из-за того, что нужно решение для консольного приложения, это избыточно. "решение для консольного приложения" = "решение для любого десктопного приложения"

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, но без метки свидетельствующей о том, что нужно решение именно для консольного приложения, будут предлагать решения для Winforms или WPF, которые совершенно неприменимы для консольного. Это всё равно что не указать что нужно решение для .net4.0 - тогда будут предлагать решения для более новых версий .net. Хотя что это я пишу... вы наверно теперь и метку .net4.0 удалите, аргументируя тем же - решения .net4.0 подходят и для более новых .net

Comment: @Raf-9600 Еще раз, метки Windows достаточно для указания, что вам нужно решение без привязки к WPF или WinForms. Если кто-то считает иначе, это их проблемы. Строго говоря, 95% кода, который кажется "заточенным под WinForms / WPF", на самом деле без проблем будет работать в консольном приложении с минимальными усилиями. Это все не аргументы для того, чтобы ставить метку console на вопрос "Как узнать разрешение экрана", который не имеет никакого отношения к консоли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогло это решение:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);
public enum DeviceCap
{
    VERTRES = 10,
    DESKTOPVERTRES = 117,

    // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetDeviceCaps.html
}  


private float getScalingFactor()
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();
    int LogicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.VERTRES);
    int PhysicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES); 

    float ScreenScalingFactor = (float)PhysicalScreenHeight / (float)LogicalScreenHeight;

    return ScreenScalingFactor; // 1.25 = 125%
}

float dpiBase = 96;
var screenRealWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * (dpiBase * getScalingFactor()) / dpiBase;
var screenRealHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * (dpiBase * getScalingFactor()) / dpiBase;
```

Код на добычу DPI был взят отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings/21450169#21450169 Но там многие жалуются что он не у всех всегда верно срабатывает, так что наиболее верным такое решение считать нельзя.

Comment: Ну тогда `dpiBase` не нужен

Answer (score 4):

Для WPF (PresentationCore.dll) под .NET 4.6.2+:

```
var dpi = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(new System.Windows.Controls.Control());
var screenRealWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * dpi.DpiScaleX;
var screenRealHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * dpi.DpiScaleY;
```

Для версий .NET ниже 4.6.2 несколько сложнее:

```
var matrixTransform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(visual).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
var screenRealWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * matrixTransform.M11;
var screenRealHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * matrixTransform.M22;
```

Где `visual` — любой визуальный элемент, но этот элемент должен быть обязательно загружен, т. е. код сработает только после того как произошло событие `Loaded`

Для WinForms (System.Drawing.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll):

```
float dpiX, dpiY, dpiBase = 96;
using (var g = new Control().CreateGraphics())
{
    dpiX = g.DpiX;
    dpiY = g.DpiY;
}
var screenRealWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * dpiX / dpiBase;
var screenRealHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * dpiY / dpiBase;
```

Впрочем, вам ничто не мешает подключить библиотеки WPF в WinForms или наоборот, а также любую из них в консольном приложении.

Comment: Вариант для WinForms всё же зависим от DPI. А для .NET ниже 4.6.2 не подходит потому что моя программа консольная, там нет визуальных объектов. Вариант для WPF жалуется на System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi, утверждая что VisualTreeHelper не содержит GetDpi.

Comment: Ну я недаром написал .NET 4.6.2+, эта функция появилась только в этой версии. Вариант для WinForms у вас не сработал? У меня правильно показал (у меня 125% стоит увеличение)

Comment: У меня вариант для WinForms выдаёт 1536 вместо 1920.

Comment: А если просто: `var screenRealWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width`?

Comment: То же самое....

Comment: Странно, а какая ОС? Можете показать настройки экрана? Какой монитор?

Comment: Обыкновенный Full HD монитор с соответствующим разрешением экрана. Win10 x64 LTS 1809.

Comment: Вот это решение по добыче DPI помогло https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450169/5105464 Получилось не красиво, но зато это работает. Ваш всего лишь чуть адаптировал под это решение, сделал так `var screenRealWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * (dpiX * getScalingFactor()) / dpiBase;`

Comment: Отлично! Напишите ответом

Comment: Если никто не подскажет более привального решения то напишу.